# Update Database Column after X Number of Failed Login Attempts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a forms login in my web site using ASP.NET MVC with C#.  All of the user profiles are stored in a `Customer` table that has the following columns:

- ID
- First_Name
- username
- password
- ActiveWebLog

with `ActiveWebLog = 0` meaning the user has not yet activated their account, and `ActiveWebLog = 1` meaning the user can login.

This is my Login action in my Controller :

```
    public ActionResult LogOnCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOnCustomer(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (MembershipService.ValidateCustomer(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                this.AuthCustomer = MembershipService.AuthCustomer;

                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("RedirectPage", "Account");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);

    }
```

What I want is to set `ActiveWebLog = -2` when the user inputs an incorrect username or password 5 times.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a LoginAttemptCount column to your table.
- Check user credentials against the database.
- If no user name, fail. It may be advisable to **not** tell the user that the username does not exist, because that supports grinding attempts to locate user names.
- If the user name matches but the LoginAttemptCount => 5 (or any number), fail.
- If the user name matches but the password is bad, increment LoginAttemptCount and fail.
- If the user name and password are good (hopefully you are using a hashed password) and LoginAttemptCount < 5, reset LoginAttemptCount to zero.

If you use this methodology, you technically don't need to modify the ActiveWebLog column when the user exceeds the bad password limit (but you certainly could).

I would put the business rules for this inside a separate class library. Your controller will probably have the basic logic to invoke this class library and modify your view based on the resulting status codes.

Comment: You must also make sure, if you are storing this approach in the database, that you are clearing out the user attempts at some point.  Nothing like locking out all your users because they mistyped their password once every couple days for a week.

Comment: @TravisJ - correct, that's why I listed the step that "if user name and password are good, reset the login attempt count to zero". Every time they successfully authenticate, the slate is wiped clean.

Comment: If the target you are trying to eliminate is bot attacks, then you should not be storing this in the user's table.  You would need to make a new table which stored IP addresses, had some sort of logging data which tracked views per day, and attempts per session, and then ensure to ban IP addresses who game sessions.

Comment: @TravisJ - Mostly agree, although I think that's out of the scope of this question. The ideal solution would leverage hardware resources to keep heavy unwanted traffic away from the application server completely, Session to control fast, repeated automated attempts, and the DB to persist failed logins and audits of those logins.

Comment: @Tim Medora : Thanks for answer me, but I really don't know what should I implement it to my project because I'm just a beginner developer in asp.net mvc.

Comment: @socheata - you can post the login code that you currently are using, and perhaps someone can tell you where these different steps should be inserted into the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["tries"] = 0;
try
{
    User.Login();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Session["tries"] = Session["tries"] + 1;
}
if (Session["tries"] > 4) 
{
    ActiveWebLog = -2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me clearly, where can I put this block of code in project, I mean in Views,Model,or Controller?

Comment: This is Session based...a user (or bot) can try 3 times then start a new Session and try all over again.